# Where j2html save the HTML file?

Tags: java, html, j2html

I'm using j2html to create an HTML file in Java, it can be a fool question, but where does the file is saved?

Answer (score 4):

j2html gives you the following options:

#### Get rendered HTML as `String`:

```
String htmlString = TagCreator.html(...).render()
```

or

```
String htmlString = TagCreator.html(...).renderFormatted()
```

These methods return the rendered HTML as `String`, *the HTML isn't written to any file.*

#### Direct the rendered HTML to an `Appendable` (which can be a `Writer`):

For example,

```
    try (Appendable writer = new FileWriter("rendered.html")) {
        TagCreator.html(...).render(writer);
    }
```

would write the HTML into the `rendered.html` file.